# SwiftのRangeの仕組みが理解出来ず苦戦しています

Tags: ios, swift

どうしてもRangeの仕組みが理解できず、開始インデックス～取得文字数を算出する方法が分かりません。
実装したい内容としては、開始インデックス～終了インデックスまでを取得するという内容です。
JAVAで実装している以下の構文をSwiftで実装する方法が分かりません。
教えて頂けますでしょうか。

```
// argContentHTML = ホームページのHTML
// HTMLをParse
// 先頭・最後インデックスを取得
intIDSearchIndex = argContentHTML.indexOf("tag1");
intIDFootSearchIndex = argContentHTML.indexOf("tag2",
                                            intIDSearchIndex + "tag1".length());

// インデックスが見つかったか判定
if(intIDSearchIndex == -1 ||
   intIDFootSearchIndex == -1){

    // どちらかのインデックスが見つからなかった場合、データ追加しない
}else{
    // 正常の場合、データ設定
    // Entry部からIDを取得
    strRet = argContentHTML.substring(intIDSearchIndex + "tag1".length(),
                                      intIDFootSearchIndex);
}
```

Comment: Swiftのコードも載せてください。

Answer (score 1):

Swift2/Xcode7を前提として、

```
import Foundation

let str = "AAAtag2BBBtag1CCCtag2DDD"
if let
    tag1 = str.rangeOfString("tag1"),
    tag2 = str.rangeOfString("tag2", range: tag1.endIndex ..< str.endIndex) {

        let strRet = String(str[tag1.endIndex ..< tag2.startIndex])
        // -> "CCC"
        // str.substringWithRange(tag1.endIndex ..< tag2.startIndex) も可
}
```

`str.rangeOfString("tag1")` で `str` 中の `"tag1"` が現れる範囲（`Range`）を得ます。
`str.rangeOfString("tag2", range: tag1.endIndex ..< str.endIndex)` は `"tag2"` が現れる範囲を`str`の `"tag1"` の終了位置から最後までの範囲で検索します。
で、標準の `subscript` を使ってスライスを得るのですが、これの型は `String`ではなく、 `String.CharacterView` なので、`String()` イニシャライザで `String` 型に変換します。

Foundationに頼らずにSwift標準ライブラリだけでやるならこんな感じでしょうか:

```
let str = "AAAtag2BBBtag1CCCtag2DDD"

let tag1 = "tag1".characters
let tag2 = "tag2".characters
let str_ = str.characters

if let
    start = str_.indices.indexOf({str_.suffixFrom($0).startsWith(tag1)})?.advancedBy(tag1.count),
    end = (start ..< str_.endIndex).indexOf({str_.suffixFrom($0).startsWith(tag2)}) {

        let strRet = String(str_[start ..< end])
        // -> "CCC"
}
```

可読性ひどいですね。
もうちょっと可読性高めるために、サブストリングの開始インデックスを探すところをファクターアウトして:

```
extension CollectionType where SubSequence.Generator.Element: Equatable {
    /// `self` 中で `sub` の開始インデックスを返す。見つからなければ `nil`。
    /// デフォルトでは `self` 全体から、rangeが与えられたときはその範囲で検索する。
    func startIndexOf(sub: SubSequence, range: Range<Index>? = nil) -> Index? {
        let range = range ?? indices
        return range.indexOf {
            self.suffixFrom($0).startsWith(sub)
        }
    }
}

let str = "AAAtag2BBBtag1CCCtag2DDD"

let tag1 = "tag1".characters
let tag2 = "tag2".characters
let str_ = str.characters

if let
    start = str_.startIndexOf(tag1)?.advancedBy(tag1.count),
    end = str_.startIndexOf(tag2, range: start ..< str_.endIndex) {

        let strRet = String(str_[start ..< end])
        // -> "CCC"
}
```

---

せっかくなのでベンチマーク
<sup>質問と関係ないですが自分の備忘録のために書かせてください</sup>

```
import XCTest

extension CollectionType where SubSequence.Generator.Element: Equatable {
    /// `self` 中で `sub` の開始インデックスを返す。見つからなければ `nil`。
    /// デフォルトでは `self` 全体から、rangeが与えられたときはその範囲で検索する。
    func startIndexOf(sub: SubSequence, range: Range<Index>? = nil) -> Index? {
        let range = range ?? indices
        return range.indexOf {
            self.suffixFrom($0).startsWith(sub)
        }
    }
}

// オリジナル回答
func find_rangeOfString(str: String, s1: String, s2: String) -> String? {
    if let
        tag1 = str.rangeOfString(s1),
        tag2 = str.rangeOfString(s2, range: tag1.endIndex ..< str.endIndex) {
            return String(str[tag1.endIndex ..< tag2.startIndex])
    }
    return nil
}

// 標準ライブラリのみ String.CharacterView で検索
func find_characters(str: String, s1: String, s2: String) -> String? {
    let s1 = s1.characters
    let s2 = s2.characters
    let str = str.characters
    if let
        start = str.startIndexOf(s1)?.advancedBy(s1.count),
        end = str.startIndexOf(s2, range: start ..< str.endIndex) {
            return String(str[start ..< end])
    }
    return nil
}

// 標準ライブラリのみ String.UTF16View で検索
func find_utf16(str: String, s1: String, s2: String) -> String? {
    let s1 = s1.utf16
    let s2 = s2.utf16
    let str = str.utf16
    if let
        start = str.startIndexOf(s1)?.advancedBy(s1.count),
        end = str.startIndexOf(s2, range: start ..< str.endIndex) {
            return String(str[start ..< end])
    }
    return nil
}

// NSScanner で検索
func find_scanner(str: String, s1: String, s2: String) -> String? {
    let scanner = NSScanner(string: str)
    var result: NSString?
    scanner.scanUpToString(s1, intoString: nil)
    scanner.scanString(s1, intoString: nil)
    scanner.scanUpToString(s2, intoString: &result)
    return scanner.atEnd ? nil : result as? String
}

// NSRegularExpression で検索
func find_regex(str: String, s1: String, s2:String) -> String? {
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(
        pattern: NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString(s1)
            + "(.*?)"
            + NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString(s2),
        options: []
    )
    if let range = regex.firstMatchInString(str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.utf16.count))?.rangeAtIndex(1) {
        return (str as NSString).substringWithRange(range)
    }
    return nil
}

class StringTestTests: XCTestCase {

    private func doTest(fn: (String, String, String) -> String?) {
        let str = "私の好物は<em>焼き魚</em>です。"
        let tag1 = "<em>"
        let tag2 = "</em>"
        XCTAssertEqual(fn(str, tag1, tag2), "焼き魚")
        measureBlock {
            for _ in 0 ..< 10000 {
                fn(str, tag1, tag2)
            }
        }
    }

    func testRangeOfString() { doTest(find_rangeOfString) }
    func testCharacters() { doTest(find_characters) }
    func testUTF16() { doTest(find_utf16) }
    func testScanner() { doTest(find_scanner) }
    func testRegex() { doTest(find_regex) }
}
```

結果 iPhone6 / iOS9.1 / Releaseビルド（複数回実行して同じ傾向 ）

```
testRangeOfString: 0.060 sec
testCharacters:    0.453 sec
testUTF16:         0.020 sec
testScanner:       0.144 sec
testRegex:         0.498 sec
```

当然、元文字列の質にも依りますので、どれかが常に一番速いわけではないはずですが、このパターンではこんな結果でした。
正規表現版は毎回パターンを作っているので遅いのは当たり前なんですが、意外にも `find_utf16` が最速。`CharacterView` を使うか `UTF16View` を使うかでこれだけの違いが出ます。何を使うべきかというのも、やりたいことと元文字列の性質によるのでなんとも言えないですが、今回のバリエーションでは、微妙に機能的な違いがあります。

```
find_rangeOfString("私の好物は焼き魚です。", s1: "", s2: "") // -> "焼き魚"
find_characters("私の好物は焼き魚です。", s1: "", s2: "") // -> nil
find_utf16("私の好物は焼き魚です。", s1: "", s2: "") // -> "焼き魚"
find_scanner("私の好物は焼き魚です。", s1: "", s2: "") // -> "焼き魚"
find_regex("私の好物は焼き魚です。", s1: "", s2: "") // -> "焼き魚"

find_rangeOfString("私の好物は焼き魚です。", s1: "", s2: "") // -> "焼き魚"
find_characters("私の好物は焼き魚です。", s1: "", s2: "") // -> nil
find_utf16("私の好物は焼き魚です。", s1: "", s2: "") // -> nil
find_scanner("私の好物は焼き魚です。", s1: "", s2: "") // -> "焼き魚"
find_regex("私の好物は焼き魚です。", s1: "", s2: "") // -> "焼き魚"
```

なんでこうなるかというと、CharacterView では 連続する国旗Emojiは 一文字として扱われるからなのですが、詳しくは https://stackoverflow.com/q/26862282/3804019

Comment: rintaroさん迅速な回答ありがとうございます。又、お返事が遅くなりまして申し訳ありません。

詳細な回答ありがとうございます。
一度テストしてみて結果報告したいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

おそらく、質問者さんのなさりたいことは、iOS/OS Xにおいては、`NSScanner`クラスを使うことになるでしょう。`NSScanner`クラスに関する情報は、AppleのドキュメントさえObjective-Cをもとに書かれたものがほとんどで、Swiftベースのものが少ないので、勉強するのはたいへんだと思いますが、慣れれば、ひじょうに少ないプログラムコードで、パースすることができるようになるでしょう。
Playgroundで動かす、サンプルコードを載せます。

```
import UIKit

// パース対象のHTMLテキストを用意する。
let htmlString = "<html>\n<head><title>Title</title>\n<body><p>Hello, world.</p>\n<p>hoge hoge</p>\n<p>fuga fuga</p>\n<p>foo foo</p>\n<p>bar bar</p>\n</body></html>"
// htmlStringを対象とするNSScannerインスタンスを作成。
let scanner = NSScanner(string: htmlString)
// 結果を格納するテキストを用意する。
var resultString = ""
// スキャンしたテキストを一時取り置きする。NSString型で、かつOptional型。
var tmpString: NSString? = ""
// スキャン開始。テキストの最後が来るまで繰り返し。
while scanner.atEnd == false {
    // <p>を検索して、その手前でスキャン停止。
    scanner.scanUpToString("<p>", intoString: nil)
    // <p>を読み飛ばす。
    scanner.scanString("<p>", intoString: nil)
    // </p>まで移動して、その間のテキストを取得。アドレス演算子（らしきもの）&があるのに注意。
    scanner.scanUpToString("</p>", intoString: &tmpString)
    // tmpStringをresultStringに追加。
    if let theString = tmpString as? String {
        resultString += theString
        // 末尾にコンマとスペースを追加。
        resultString += ", "
    }
    // tmpStringを初期化する。
    tmpString = nil
}
print(resultString)
```

結果：

> Hello, world., hoge hoge, fuga fuga, foo foo, bar bar,

※似たクラスに`NSXMLParser`というものがあります。XML⊃HTMLなので、HTMLのパースにも使えるんじゃないかと思われますが、単独タグ、`<br>`、`<img>`などを使っていると、うまく動かないので、お勧めになりません。（`<br/>`、`<img/>`を求められる＞）

Comment: Harawoさん迅速な回答ありがとうございます。又、お返事が遅くなりまして申し訳ありません。

詳細な回答ありがとうございます。
一度テストしてみて結果報告したいと思います。